# Взаимодействие Kamailio(OpenSER) и Asterisk

Tags: nat, sip, asterisk, voip

На сервере, смотрящем в интернет настроены Kamailio в качестве SIP-регистратора и Asterisk с диалпланами. Kamailio перенаправляет пакеты на Asterisk. Соединение между пирами устанавливается, а rtp-трафик при этом не ходит между клиентами, которые находятся за NAT. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Настроено все точно по документации на офф. сайте. Непонятно, в какую сторону копать

Answer (score 1):

В файле конфигуации sip.conf в секции которая отвечает за пиры которые за нат пропишите

```
nat=force_rport,comedia
```

После перезагрузите конфиги `asterisk -rx "sip reload"`